# How to view hidden console errors in js?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, error-handling

I am inspecting chrome extension popup and I see there is an error triggered but I can't view it. Is there a way I can se the error ? I guess, from blogs I were searching about JS errors that should be a syntax error, in this case how can I find the problem ? My code looks correct and didn't have this issue in past, just came up from nowhere.

I tried to use try...catch on full JS file but still can't find the error.
[image]

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: unfortunately not, it is part of a bigger project I can't share

Comment: Can you explain why you cant view the error in the console window?

Comment: I added a screenshot with the console, in top right corner it says hidden error, and the error message is not visible

Comment: Can you remove the `ifmail` text from search box and take a screenshot?

Comment: Yes, removing the ifmail showed me the error which was a file not found error. That ifmail wasn't put by me but was there by default, so I supposed it should be there.

Comment: Please remove the `ifmail` as its a search keyword. It's cached by the browser. Please add the screenshot without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove `ifmail` from the console in browser, as it's just a search keyword. After that, you shall see what the error is, and then know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Because of `ifmail` filter was added by default I couldn't see the file not found error. So the problem was related with using wrong name for the js file. Thanks to Robin Thomas for helping me.
[image]